# Инжектировать дженерик сервис через Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, C#

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection

Пытаюсь инжектировать дженерик сервис через `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`, но не могу получить объект из `ServiceProvider`

```
public interface Interface<T, T2>
{
}

public class Realisation<T, T2> : Interface<T, T2>
{
}


public static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddScoped(typeof(Interface<,>), typeof(Realisation<,>))
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        
        var servive = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Interface<,>));
    }
}
```

В результате получаю ошибку ``` Implementation type 'App.Console.Realisation``2[T,T2]' can't be converted to service type 'App.Console.Interface``2[T,T2] ```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Так при работе с объектом, вы ведь должны задать конкретные значения генерику, а не работать с абстракцией. Собственно и пробуйте просить конкретные типы, а не `<,>`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мне нужен именно дженерик сервис, на подобие инжектирования пайпов для MediatR вроде `.AddScoped(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidatorPipe<,>))`

Comment: Я не говорю сейчас про регистрацию, туда вы успешно зарегистрировали, я говорю про получение. Вот забудьте про контейнер и внедрение зависимостей, просто создайте `class Realisation<T, T2>`, как вы это сделаете руками? Наверно `var res = new Realisation<int, string>();`, верно? Вы не сможете сделать `new Realisation<,>()`, вам это просто не позволит IDE, ибо вы не указали требуемые типы. Вот также и через контейнер, вы обязаны передать туда нужный тип для получения, условно `.GetService<Interface<int, string>>()`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ как я могу это сделать во время выполнения? Например есть две переменный типа `Type` для T и T2. Мне нужно получить `.GetService(typeof(Interface<T,T2>))` не зная заранее какие типа T1 и T2

Comment: Дженерики - это сущности времени _компиляции_. Переменные типа - это сущности времени _исполнения_ (рантайма). Если ваши типы становятся известны только во время исполнения, значит дженерики вам не нужны.

Comment: "Как я могу" - ну. например, при помощи метода [Type.MakeGenericType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype), который позволяет создать тип и указать в рантайме все его `T`, потом просто `.GetService(...)`, будет вам то, что хотите. Но я надеюсь вы осознаете, что это костыли, и скорей всего вы усложняете себе задачу лишним?) Обычно достаточно одного генерика, либо его еще можно обернуть в другой генерик метод/класс, передав типа куда надо, но чтоб вот так, в рантайме, неизвестные типы...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, это ровно то что мне было нужно) Можете это добавить как ответ чтобы я его выбрал

Comment: Пожалуй откажусь, можете написать его самостоятельно.